# Schema.org for a list of blogs

Tags: blog, schema.org

What is the recommended Schema.org markup for a page with a list of blog posts?

For example this page: https://www.ultimatelifestylist.com/author/mahum-masood/

Would it be: `ItemList`, `CollectionPage` or `BlogPosting`?

I'm trying to link all the pages in a schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) for the page wouldn’t make sense. The page contains several `BlogPosting` items, but the page itself is not a `BlogPosting`.

Using [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) is appropriate, but note that this is not a `WebPage` type. It could be the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) of a `WebPage`. An alternative could be to use [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog), but it’s also possible to use this only on the blog’s front page

So if you want to use a type for the actual page, you should use [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) or one of its sub-types. The [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) you mentioned is the best match for a page listing all blog posts of a specific author.

If the focus of the page is the person instead of the posts this person wrote, you could consider using [`AboutPage`](http://schema.org/AboutPage) with a `mainEntity` of [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person).